# Only Home Page not working with IIS 6 and Windows Authentication in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, iis-6

I am trying to convert my mvc applcation to run under windows authentication and have followed the steps here: http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

**This doesn't work - localhost/myapp/Home.mvc/index** - home is my entry view with controller.

I get a 403 error when I load the applciaiton at first and then a 404 error if I try to access  from the address bar.

**All other routes work from address bar and the applaciiton works from then on, like - localhost/myapp/controller.mvc/index**

My Global.asax file looks like:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Default",
          "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
          new { action = "Index", id = "" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "Root",
          "",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
```

I am using a cut down version the aspnet membership model using only the tables: user, role and usersInRole.

When I check User,Identity.Name I get what I expect.

I've had this appraoch working before so don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I can provide more information if required.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you execute the registermvc.wcf script? or Did you add the new extension to IIS as stated in your link?

Answer (score 0):

What about localhost/myapp/Home.mvc/***I***ndex